# Angular 6 - Material Table - Get selected row values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Am trying to pass selected row value from one component to another on the button click. but in this, [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1hkf2?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts), from where can get selected row values and pass the selected value on button click? followed by that routing will happen

`this.selection.selected` returns the same object multiple time. how to stop that.
i want to pass the value like

```
    <button (click)='onSelect(row)'>select row </button>

    onSelect(id){
    this.selectedRowValue = id
        //some logics
    }
```

could someone tell me how to pass the selected row value from one component to another?

Answer (score 2):

If you add this code in your component, `selectedElements` object changes with every selection change event

```
  selectedElements: PeriodicElement[] = [];

  constructor(){
    this.selection.changed.asObservable().subscribe(a => this.selectedElements = [...this.selection.selected]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but how the selected value? `console.log(this.selection.selected)` not returning selected row value properly

Comment: Forked your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1hkf2-ynzdnt?file=app/table-selection-example.ts) and `this.selection.selected` returns all selected items

Comment: sorry again. actually, am looking for to send the selected value to button click event so that i can do page routing. how to pass the selected to button click. that' s what my issue